# How to modify process function in simple wallet project?

Tags: python, docker-compose, transactions, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am learning Hyperledger sawtooth , I cloned simplewallet project and tried to run stuff and play with function to learn how is this project working.
I could successfully create client function and add it properly. but changing or adding stuff to the transcation processor at `simplewallet-tp.py` isn't causing anything . i tried to change the deposit function to add the amount X2 , i even tried to create errors inside it but once i run docker, the deposit function works the same and nothing changed .

What could I be possibly doing wrong ?

Comment: first you could add links to project and definition of `Hyperledger sawtooth`  in question (not in comment)

Comment: next you should show code and how you use it - and you use docker. We can't read in your mind - you have to add all details in question (not in comment)

Comment: @furas sorry this is the first time ever i ask something on stack overflow.